# JSF Target unreachable, returned null on session timeout on login

Tags: java, jsf, session, session-timeout

I've recently tried to upgrade a system to timeout user sessions through the `web.xml` file, set to 10 minutes, with a `Filter` redirecting to my login page as well as a `PhaseListener` to keep track of user activity.

My Login bean, on instantiation, does the following:

```
private User user; //this already has getters/setters

public LoginBean() {
    log.info("Instantiating Login Bean...");
    if(!hasSessionData("user")) {
        user = new User();
        Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
        user.setDealer(dealer);
        setSessionData("user",user);
    }       
}
```

This opens the login form and uses `User` to contain login details for submission. However, if I sit on the login screen for more than 10 minutes (session expire) and I attempt to login, I get an error.

```
Aug 01, 2013 10:32:20 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase execute
WARNING: /Login30FrmView.xhtml @108,92 value="#{loginBean.user.dealerId}": Target Unreachable, 'user' returned null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /Login30FrmView.xhtml @108,92 value="#{loginBean.user.dealerId}": Target Unreachable, 'user' returned null
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:62)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:92)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:942)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:868)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1072)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:672)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1058)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:234)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1058)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$3.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:447)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:240)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processValidators(AjaxViewRoot.java:463)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Aug 01, 2013 10:32:20 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase doPhase
SEVERE: JSF1054: (Phase ID: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3, View ID: /Login30FrmView.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@7d137b]

I am wondering why user is returning null when the LoginBean is still initialized according to log. On session expire, `user` in session expires as well, so `if(!hasSessionData("user"))` should return true and initialize `user` again. But if user has to be re-initialized on page load and it times out on page...how can that be done? My `Filter` redirects to login whenever a session is destroyed like so:

```
if (isSessionInvalid(httpServletRequest)) {
    String timeoutUrl = httpServletRequest.getContextPath() + "/" + getTimeoutPage();
          httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(timeoutUrl);
          System.out.println("Redirecting to login page");
          return;
          }
    }
```

But somehow I need this to trigger when the form is submitted and session expired, which it doesn't seem to do as it is...I don't have much experience with this so I want to know if this is possible? How can I get `user` initialized again for form submit once session expires?

(Note that refreshing the page makes everything fine again, but I'm going to get a lot of complaints from end-users if I let scary error messages even appear.)

EDIT: My login submit uses a `<h:commandButton>` and points to a listener in my `LoginBean`. Is there any way to catch if this is submitted so I can revert to login page when the above occurs? This may be a possible alternate solution. I just really want that error to go away, even if it jumps the user back to login without explanation.

Comment: Have you added `@SessionScoped` in the User Class?

Comment: Are you sure that's all the stacktrace?

Comment: Related (since you didn't show all your managed bean configuration): http://stackoverflow.com/q/8728487/1065197

Comment: @MatheusFreitas I'm using JSF 1.1 so I use faces-config.xml to set it in session scope. Like I said, login works completely fine until I idle at the login page long enough for session timeout.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've added the full stacktrace. Also saw all the various related errors, I think mine is unique in that login already works; just not when you stay on the login page long enough to time out. Refreshing the page allows you to login normally.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question since I found a solution. I simply had to add this line to my Login Form.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>
```

This refreshes the form before timeout to preserve the session, thus ensuring that there is always a `user` in session since refreshing instantiates the bean and loads the page again.